# Remote update of MS-Access frontend applications

Tags: windows-10, command-line, batch, batch-file, file-transfer

We are doing quite many changes in our ms-access front-ends, so we need to update the ms-access applications often. I have tried to use PSEXEC for the remote updates, but it seems to be a problem with the mounted local network drives and PSEXEC.

We have a 1000 Mbit network, with 16 windows 10 computers.

We have a Linux server where the shared databases are located, and the updated access front-ends are uploaded, waiting for each user to activate bat files for copying the access front-ends to the respective Windows 10 computers.

Each Windows 10 Computer has its own batch file shortcut to a computer-specific bat file, which is located on the Linux server.

The server is mounted as drive K: on all machines.

The bat files on the user1 Windows 10 PC is located on k:\Database\Development\Install\PC1.bat and look like this:

Bat file Name: PC1.bat

```
taskkill /f /fi "imagename eq msaccess.exe"

del C:\Users\user1\Desktop\program1_v*.*
del C:\Users\user1\Desktop\program4_v*.*
del /s /q d:\User_Program\*.*

xcopy /e /q /y k:\Database\Development\Install\Program_shcut\*.* C:\Users\User1\Desktop\
xcopy /e /q /y k:\Database\Development\Install\Program\*.* D:\User_Program\
```

I would really appreciate a solution to this task, which would save me a lot of time, and secure that all applications are updated simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to my problem, by making, on the remote Computer, a Task Schedule named "Update_Programs", with an action "k:\Database\Development\Install\PC1.bat" and no trigger.

On the locale computer, I made a batch file to execute the Task Scheduler named "Update_Programs" on the remote machine.

```
@ECHO off
psexec \\ip no -u username -p password -s -d cmd.exe /c schtasks /run /tn Update_Programs
```